# Single column data in h2o model needs 2 columns to work

Tags: h2o

Having had AutoML() recommend a model after I experimented with a single column of data and needed to identify a target as a step-1 of the single data to train the successful model I now want to use the model on test (live) data. The model however wants a 2 column input and when I use a padded second column "target" = [0] then the model returns the same predictive output and I am guessing it is because of the second null zero entry column. Is there a way around this issue please ?

I have tried using the model with just one column and it errored and I have added the second padding column all zeros and while the code worked the prediction is always the same with differing inputs

Comment: Is it possible for you to post some code sample?
Especially, it is still not clear for me what you mean with `needed to identify a target as a step-1 of the single data to train the succesful model`. AutoML is supervised, so your data need at least 2 columns of data: at least 1 feature, and the target. Then, for predictions, you test input data need at least the feature, it should not require the target column (doesn't make sense for a supervised model). Having a code sample would help me to understand how you're configuring AutoML and how you're doing the prediction, thanks.

Comment: I am wanting to use the h2o.AutoML() function to parse a single column of data in order to find the best ML process for predicting the next row . To do this I have to create a second column with a .step(-1)  of the origonal column which aligns the new col of data with the origonal test row. The AutoML function produces a leader board with a best ML process. Using this best model it requires a second col per its training, using a second col of zeros the model works but no matter the input into the model.predict() the same value is returned.  
Wise Recruitment
 27 mins ago